# JSON Format for map

Tags: java, json, gson

How to create json string for the below format

```
    Map<String, Map<String, Map<String ,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>>>>>
```

where VirtualNE is a DTO class

```
 public class VirtualNE {

private VirtualNePK primaryKey;
private String status;
private String lockId;
private String frequency1;
private String frequency2;

     getter & setter goes here
 }
```

where VirtualNePK as primarykey class nested inside VirtualNE dto class

```
public class VirtualNePK {
private String pCode;
private String neType;
private String src;
private String destination;

  getter & setter goes here
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

This code will convert your `Map` to `json string` within provided format:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson ( map1 );
```

### Main:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;

public class Main
{

    public static void main ( String [ ] args )
    {

        //virtualNE related object
        VirtualNePK pk = new VirtualNePK ( );
        pk.setDestination ( "destination1" );
        pk.setNeType ( "type1" );
        pk.setpCode ( "1" );
        pk.setSrc ( "source1" );

        VirtualNE virtualNE = new VirtualNE ( );
        virtualNE.setFrequency1 ( "freq1" );
        virtualNE.setFrequency2 ( "freq1" );
        virtualNE.setLockId ( "lock1" );
        virtualNE.setPrimaryKey ( pk );
        virtualNE.setStatus ( "status1" );      

        //Virtual Ne Set
        Set<VirtualNE> virtualNESet = new HashSet<VirtualNE> ( );

        virtualNESet.add ( virtualNE );

        //set
        Map<String,Set<VirtualNE> > map4 =  new HashMap<> ( );
        map4.put ( "string4" , virtualNESet );
        //Map3
        Map<String,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>> > map3 = new HashMap<> ( );
        map3.put ( "string3" , map4 );
        //Map2
        Map< String,Map<String ,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>>> > map2 =  new HashMap<> ( );
        map2.put ( "string2" , map3 );

        //map1
        Map<String, Map<String, Map<String ,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>>>>> map1 = new HashMap<String, Map<String, Map<String ,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>>>>> ( );
        map1.put ( "string1" , map2 );

        //Convert to Json
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        String json = gson.toJson ( map1 );

        System.out.println ( json.toString ( ) );

    }

}
```

### Output:

```
{
  "string1": {
    "string2": {
      "string3": {
        "string4": [
          {
            "primaryKey": {
              "pCode": "1",
              "neType": "type1",
              "src": "source1",
              "destination": "destination1"
            },
            "status": "status1",
            "lockId": "lock1",
            "frequency1": "freq1",
            "frequency2": "freq1"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Reverse:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String ,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>>>>> map = gson.fromJson(json,new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String ,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>>>>>>(){}.getType ( ) );

System.out.println ( map.toString ( )  );
```

### Output:

```
{string1={string2={string3={string4=[VirtualNE [primaryKey=VirtualNePK [pCode=1, neType=type1, src=source1, destination=destination1], status=status1, lockId=lock1, frequency1=freq1, frequency2=freq1]]}}}}
```

Comment: Thanks for help. facing another issue. now I am doing reverse. Type relMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String ,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>>>>>>(){}.getType(); gson.fromJson("o/p json sting",relMapType ).. getting following exception .....Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String .. can you please assist on this.

Comment: Excellent it works. but why its not working when I load json file . like          Reader reader = new FileReader("D:\\work.json");
                VirtualNE staff = gson.fromJson(json, relMapType);
               System.out.println(staff);                                                            (or  )     Type relMapType = new TypeToken<Map<String, Map<String, Map<String ,Map<String, Set<VirtualNE>>>>>>(){}.getType();  String json1 = gson.fromJson("json string",relMapType );. Is anything  missing here.

Comment: @Niru... Your question was very clear and i already answered. If you have more problems i suggest to open a new one.

Comment: @Manu... If it helped you out, please mark the question asnwered. gl